# Why split a View Binding object into nullable and non-nullable properties in a fragment?

Tags: android

In the [documentation for View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) they show this code for using it in a fragment:

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

I understand that **_binding** should be nullable since the fragment can outlive its views, and it should be set to null when the views are destroyed. What I don't get is why they suggest using **binding** (without the underscore) and the not-null assertion operator to basically bypass the null safety features of Kotlin. I must be missing something, so could someone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: I also don't understand the logic behind it. Renaming `_binding` to `binding` and deleting the original `binding` seems to result in the exact same behaviour of code. Both would crash with a nullpointer exception if you access it while it's null. Although you would need to use `binding!!` instead of `binding` every time you access it but that still looks much cleaner than the proposed  way.